# Disassembling C to Assembly x86_64 with GCC 32 bit vs 64 bit Instructions

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, disassembly

I am trying to learn assembly x86_64 by reverse engineering programs to see how assembly works. I do this by disassembling my C code into assembly with the gcc compiler. The command I use for this is

```
gcc -O0 -S my_C_code.c
```

However, in doing so the compiler produces a mixture of 32 bit and 64 bit instructions. This confuses me as I thought the compiler would only produce 64 bit instructions. An example of this is :

```
subq $32 , %rsp 
movl %edi , -20(%rbp)
movl %esi , -24(%rbp)
movq %rdx , -32(%rbp)
```

The compiler produces the first instruction using a 64 bit instruction but uses 32 bit for the next 2. Other parts of the program are similar. For context , the code snippet above was taken from a subroutine that takes 3 arguments : an integer , an integer and a pointer respectively.

From what I've read so far , I think that this happens because 32 bit registers are used for integers and 64 bit for pointers. This raises another question. I am able to successfully change the %edi register and everything related to it to 64 bit. However, in doing so for the %esi register , I face a segmentation fault. Could this be due to 16 byte stack alignment ?

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour].

Comment: That is **probably** because; the higher bytes of the data index register hold the main address and the lower bytes (`edi`) hold the auxiliary address (offset). The same is true for the stack register; higher bytes hold the main address and the lower bytes (`esi`) hold the auxiliary address. So, `movl %edi , -20(%rbp)` means; *copy the auxiliary address of data index register (offset from the data index) to the address 20 bytes lower than the base pointer*.

Comment: Probably your C code uses `int`. I think the compiler recognized `int` as 4-bytes therefore 32 bit register was used. What happens if you use something like `int64_t`?

Comment: I am not sure if I fully understand. I understand offset in reference to the stack but not with registers. What would happen if I were to copy the main address instead auxiliary? Because I can seem to do `movq %rdi , -20(%rbp)` but not `movq %rsi , -24($rbp)` . How does the auxiliary and main differ between the two as they both refer to integers.

Comment: These registers (data & stack registers) are special purpose registers. Assume the higher bytes storing the "*state*" and the lower bytes storing the "*city*" part of a full address.

Comment: Thank you couyoh . Using int64_t does indeed turn it all into 64 bit registers with their corresponding instructions. Still a little confused about why manually changing the instructions wasn't working on this program however it was working for other programs. I think it is related to what ssd was talking about earlier in the post

Comment: Your second question is unclear, please [edit] and show your code instead of describing it.  This is a general recommendation, it's always better to show your _actual_ code instead of giving a description which will most likely be misinterpreted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think that this happens because 32 bit registers are used for integers and 64 bit for pointers.

Probably your C code uses `int`. I think the compiler recognized `int` as 4-bytes therefore 32-bit register was used. If you use something like `int64_t`, 64-bit registers would be used.

> I am able to successfully change the %edi register and everything related to it to 64 bit. However, in doing so for the %esi register , I face a segmentation fault.

Remember that `esi`/`edi` is 4-bytes but `rsi`/`rdi` is 8-bytes.

The original state is

```
+--------+-----+
| rbp-24 | esi |
+--------+-----+
| rbp-20 | edi |
+--------+-----+
```

If you change the `edi` to the `rdi`, then

```
+--------+------------------------+
| rbp-24 |          esi           |
+--------+------------------------+
| rbp-20 | High-bytes of rdi      |
+--------+------------------------+
| rbp-16 | Low-bytes of rdi (edi) |
+--------+------------------------+
```

If you change the `esi` to the `rsi`, then

```
+--------+------------------------+-----+
| rbp-24 |   High-bytes of rsi    |     |
+--------+------------------------+-----+
| rbp-20 | Low-bytes of rsi (esi) | edi |
+--------+------------------------+-----+
```

You'll notice `rsi` contains the `edi` value.

I don't know your C code so it's a guess, but probably a function call. Perhaps your code crashes if the second argument (which is `rsi` on System V AMD64 ABI) is an unexpected value.